# equivalent of 'which' function in Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm a newbie to C++ and Rcpp. Suppose, I have a vector

```
t1<-c(1,2,NA,NA,3,4,1,NA,5)
```

and I want to get a index of elements of t1 that are `NA`. I can write:

```
NumericVector retIdxNA(NumericVector x) {

    // Step 1: get the positions of NA in the vector
    LogicalVector y=is_na(x);

    // Step 2: count the number of NA
    int Cnt=0;
    for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++) {
       if (y[i]) {
         Cnt++;
       }
    }

    // Step 3: create an output matrix whose size is same as that of NA
    // and return the answer
    NumericVector retIdx(Cnt);
    int Cnt1=0;
    for (int i=0;i<x.size();i++) {
       if (y[i]) {
          retIdx[Cnt1]=i+1;
          Cnt1++;
       }
    }
    return retIdx;
}
```

then I get

```
retIdxNA(t1)
[1] 3 4 8
```

I was wondering:

(i) is there any equivalent of `which` in Rcpp?

(ii) is there any way to make the above function shorter/crisper? In particular, is there any easy way to combine the Step 1, 2, 3 above?

Comment: See also https://github.com/romainfrancois/Rcpp-book/blob/master/chapters/threading/which.md for threaded version of `which`

Comment: glad you found it useful. I'm aware it needs a rewrite. But the basic ideas are there.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recent version of [RcppArmadillo](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.armadillo.html) have functions to identify the indices of finite and non-finite values.

So this code

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::uvec whichNA(arma::vec x) {
  return arma::find_nonfinite(x);
}

/*** R
t1 <- c(1,2,NA,NA,3,4,1,NA,5)
whichNA(t1)
*/
```

yields your desired answer (module the off-by-one in C/C++ as they are zero-based):

```
R> sourceCpp("/tmp/uday.cpp")

R> t1 <- c(1,2,NA,NA,3,4,1,NA,5)

R> whichNA(t1)
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]    3
[3,]    7
R>
```

Rcpp can do it too if you first create the sequence to subset into:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::IntegerVector which2(Rcpp::NumericVector x) {
  Rcpp::IntegerVector v = Rcpp::seq(0, x.size()-1);
  return v[Rcpp::is_na(x)];
}
```

Added to code above it yields:

```
R> which2(t1)
[1] 2 3 7
R>
```

The logical subsetting is also somewhat new in Rcpp.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
#include <Rcpp.h> 
using namespace Rcpp; 

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector which4( NumericVector x) {

    int nx = x.size();
    std::vector<int> y;
    y.reserve(nx);

    for(int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        if (R_IsNA(x[i])) y.push_back(i+1);
    }

    return wrap(y);
}
```

which we can run like this in R:

```
> which4(t1)
[1] 3 4 8
```

**Performance**

Note that we have changed the above solution to reserve space for the output vector. This replaces `which3` which is:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector which3( NumericVector x) {
    int nx = x.size();
    IntegerVector y;
    for(int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        // if (internal::Rcpp_IsNA(x[i])) y.push_back(i+1);
        if (R_IsNA(x[i])) y.push_back(i+1);
    }
    return y;
}
```

Then the performance on a vector 9 elements long is the following with `which4` the fastest:

```
> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(retIdxNA(t1), whichNA(t1), which2(t1), which3(t1), which4(t1), 
+    replications = 10000, order = "relative")[1:4]
          test replications elapsed relative
5   which4(t1)        10000    0.14    1.000
4   which3(t1)        10000    0.16    1.143
1 retIdxNA(t1)        10000    0.17    1.214
2  whichNA(t1)        10000    0.17    1.214
3   which2(t1)        10000    0.25    1.786
```

Repeating this for a vector 9000 elements long the Armadillo solution comes in quite a bit faster than the others.  Here `which3` (which is the same as `which4` except it does not reserve space for the output vector) comes in worst while `which4` comes second.

```
> tt <- rep(t1, 1000)
> benchmark(retIdxNA(tt), whichNA(tt), which2(tt), which3(tt), which4(tt), 
+   replications = 1000, order = "relative")[1:4]
          test replications elapsed relative
2  whichNA(tt)         1000    0.09    1.000
5   which4(tt)         1000    0.79    8.778
3   which2(tt)         1000    1.03   11.444
1 retIdxNA(tt)         1000    1.19   13.222
4   which3(tt)         1000   23.58  262.000
```

Comment: Sure, but why not use the non-loop two-liner I posted? Add a +1 offset at will to the sequence if you think that matters.

Comment: For compactness and readability one of your solutions would be better but if speed is an issue then I would suspect this solution is faster as it seems its often the case that Rcpp runs faster with devectorized code.  Also its closer to the poster's solution.  Note that I did give you one of your upvotes.

Comment: How about if you measured it?

Comment: OK. Added them. `which4` wins on the basis of speed for small vectors and `whichNA` for large.

Comment: @Dirk, By the way, originally I had omitted `wrap` in `which4` but that failed to compile.  Why does it not convert the return value automatically without `wrap`?  Also would it be feasible to add a `reserve` method to `NumericVector` as it seems to make a huge difference on long vectors?

Comment: This has all been discussed before. `std::vector<>` != `SEXP`-based R vectors, so `wrap()` is needed and `reserve()` would likely involve inefficient copying. And nice to see that the Armadillo version looks pretty good on vectors that matter.  Personally, I would not worry too much about `n=9`.

Comment: If the reservation of space could be specified at the time that the vector is created that would not involve copying.

Comment: We have `Rcpp::NumericVector(int n)` just like standard STL vectors, and it is fairly common to use the size when known. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I was looking for something that allocated the space but did not make the vector that large so that expanding the vector up to that size will not have a significant  impact.  `data.table` has something like that.  An R data.table has a length (no of cols) and a truelength (no of cols that it can expand to without significant impact).  std::vector in C++ has this with reserve.

Comment: Actually I believe that R vectors have a true length too in addition to the actual length although the true length cannot be accessed from R.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck the "true length" thing does not really do what the name implies. It is mainly used in R with hash tables but has nothing to do with some sort of maximum capacity as the name implies.

Answer (score 4):

All of the solutions above are serial. Although not trivial, it is quite possible to take advantage of threading for implementing `which`. See [this write up](https://github.com/romainfrancois/Rcpp-book/blob/master/chapters/threading/which.md) for more details. Although for such small sizes, it would not more harm than good. Like taking a plane for a small distance, you lose too much time at airport security..

R implements `which` by allocating memory for a logical vector as large as the input, does a single pass to store the indices in this memory, then copy it eventually into a proper logical vector.

Intuitively this seems less efficient than a double pass loop, but not necessarily, as copying a data range is cheap. See more details [here](https://github.com/romainfrancois/Rcpp-book/blob/master/chapters/threading/which.md).

Comment: There somewhere. https://github.com/romainfrancois/Rcpp-book/tree/master/chapters/threading/code The code might need a refresh as it is 4 months old. Note however that it needs the `<thread>` header which AFAIK is not available on current Rtools windows toolset ..

Comment: This all very nice, and you may enjoy the [keynote Luke gave at our conference](http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2014/talk/LukeTierney.pdf) as there will be similar approaches based on OpenMP in R "at some point", but also entire orthogonal to what the OP asked for: a solution for Rcpp (not Rcpp11) that can be used today,

Comment: You can use Rcpp11 today.

Comment: Just how you can use C++11 in Rcpp today too. But you still haven't given the OP an answer he can use.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, what is the main difference between Rcpp and Rcpp11?

Comment: @uday the main difference is who pulls the strings and as a consequence how each evolve. Rcpp11 is a complete rewrite. Only keeping the best parts, and focused on modern C++, and innovating. OTOH, Rcpp is stable and compatible with older C++ standard.

Answer (score -5):

Just write a function for yourself like:

```
which_1<-function(a,b){
return(which(a>b))
}
```

Then pass this function into rcpp.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)