# Efficiently construct GRanges/IRanges from Rle vector

Tags: r, bioinformatics, bioconductor, run-length-encoding, iranges

I have a Run length encoded vector representing some value at every position on the genome, in order.  As a toy example suppose I had just one chromosome of length 10, then I would have a vector looking like

```
library(GenomicRanges)

set.seed(1)
toyData = Rle(sample(1:3,10,replace=TRUE))
```

I would like to coerce this into a GRanges object.  The best I can come up with is

```
gr = GRanges('toyChr',IRanges(cumsum(c(0,runLength(toyData)[-nrun(toyData)])),
                              width=runLength(toyData)),
             toyData = runValue(toyData))
```

which works, but is quite slow.  Is there a faster way to construct the same object?

Comment: you can use `start(toyData)-1` to get the starts of the interval but it doesn't improve speed.

Comment: @NicE Thanks for tip, even if it's not faster it is much clearer and concise.

Comment: <The whole cumsum can be replaced by `start(toyData)-1`>

Comment: @user1356855, what are some typical chromosome lengths you would encounter? Also, would 3 be enough variation in your real-world application (e.g. could you have `sample(1:15,10^8,replace=TRUE)`)?

Comment: @JosephWood Yeah, the values stored with genomic data are often real numbers so 3 would not be enough... But I would accept almost any answer. Longest genome: 247,249,719 for example? Chr1 humans...

Comment: Could it be, that the problem is not transforming the `Rle` object. It is the `IRanges`/`GRanges` function which is in general the slow part?

Comment: @Jimbou, that is exactly what I'm thinking. I'm wondering how the folks at [https://bioconductor.org/](https://bioconductor.org/) would handle this.

Answer (score 4):

As @TheUnfunCat pointed out, the OP's solution is pretty solid. The solution below is only moderately faster than the original solution. I tried almost every combination of `base R` and couldn't beat the efficiency `Rle` from the `S4Vectors` package, thus I resorted to `Rcpp`.  Here is the main function :

```
GenomeRcpp <- function(v) {
    x <- WhichDiffZero(v)
    m <- v[c(1L,x+1L)]
    s <- c(0L,x)
    e <- c(x,length(v))-1L
    GRanges('toyChr',IRanges(start = s, end = e), toyData = m)
}
```

The `WhichDiffZero` is the `Rcpp` function that pretty much does the exact same thing as `which(diff(v) != 0)` in `base R`. Much credit goes to [@G.Grothendieck](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23850711/4408538).

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
IntegerVector WhichDiffZero(IntegerVector x) {
    int nx = x.size()-1;
    std::vector<int> y;
    y.reserve(nx);
    for(int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        if (x[i] != x[i+1]) y.push_back(i+1);
    }
    return wrap(y);
}
```

Below are some benchmarks:

```
set.seed(437)
testData <- do.call(c,lapply(1:10^5, function(x) rep(sample(1:50, 1), sample(1:30, 1))))

microbenchmark(GenomeRcpp(testData), GenomeOrig(testData))
Unit: milliseconds
                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
GenomeRcpp(testData) 20.30118 22.45121 26.59644 24.62041 27.28459 198.9773   100   a
GenomeOrig(testData) 25.11047 27.12811 31.73180 28.96914 32.16538 225.1727   100   a

identical(GenomeRcpp(testData), GenomeOrig(testData))
[1] TRUE
```

I've been working on this off and on for the past few days and I'm definitely not satisfied. I'm hoping that someone will take what I've done (as it is a different approach) and create something much better.

Comment: This might mean the OPs metadata contained non-vectorized data? Having objects in "vectors" is possible in pandas, dunno about R...

Comment: I have to admit, I'm not completely satisfied either.  It seems like the GRanges object is sufficiently similar to a Rle vector (for the one chromosome) that the construction step should be basically instant. Instead it's the slowest part of my code.  Clearly I don't understand the internals well enough to know why this is wrong/how to make it faster.  The Rcpp alternative is neat though and does give some extra speed.  Thanks!